# Closing windows with MacRuby and the Scripting Bridge

Tags: ruby, cocoa, macruby, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to write a quick script that will close all but the current window for the terminal application.  This script uses MacRuby and the Scripting Bridge.  Heres' what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/macruby

framework "Foundation"
framework "ScriptingBridge"

terminal = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.Terminal")
terminal.windows[2].close while terminal.windows.count > 1
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `close' for #<TerminalWindow:0x40033b0e0> (NoMethodError)
```

This approach seems to work fine with AppleScript.  Does anybody know why it's failing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a copy of the `TerminalWindow` API [here](http://www.mugginsoft.com/html/kosmictask/ScriptingBridgeDox/Apple/Terminal/OS-X-10.7/Terminal-2.2.2/html/interface_terminal_window.html#details).  Using that, all I needed to do was:

```
TerminalSaveOptionsNo = 'no  '.unpack('N').first
terminal.windows[1].closeSaving(TerminalSaveOptionsNo, savingIn: nil)
```